# Color became weird after running a game in Wine?

Tags: graphics, wine, display, games, colors

Alright, so, I'm not entirely sure how to explain this... Screenshots don't show anything wrong, and Skype friends on screen share say it looks fine. But restarting fixes it. (For the most part (more on this later.))

After running Halo: Combat Evolved on Wine for like the millionth time, and it worked fine before, as soon as I ran it, the color on my display went haywire. To put it simply, a purple floor, for example, turned into a periwinkle blue. All the color transitions were sudden and pixelated.

And it wasn't just in the game, my entire screen had its colors go crazy. Skype calls became a bright blue, and a dark red became a brighter red. All color transitions were harsh and pixelated. It also seemed to leave a permanent effect on some other parts of my computer.

For instance, the login has the text box and everything around it as a bright white, making it impossible to actually see anything on it. I haven't noticed much else, but after restarting, everything but the text box is back to normal. I have all my graphics drivers and everything, but I was starting an update and I had a power outage.

However things ran fine afterwards anyway, besides minor details like some parts of my computer saying 13.10 and others saying 14.10(04?

Don't remember which it said...) Anyway, if anyone could help, that would be great. Do I have to reinstall my computer or anything harsh? Or is there a simple fix in WineConfig I don't know about?

Comment: where did you see 13.10?

Comment: I saw 13.10 on the login menu, but 14.04 on the loading screen. Also, a problem I think may be related, now when I sign in, it just reloads the sign in prompt. I can still use the terminal through Ctrl+Alt+F1-6 though.

Comment: I am having the same problem... Did you find the solution?